# How to vertically center item on page

Tags: html, r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I am creating an ioslides presentation but the only issue is the title page. By default, the items show in the lower left corner. Below is the YAML that I am using

```
 $$\\[-4in]$$:
 title: Something
 subtitle: <span style="font-size:22px; font-family:'Arial'; color:#0A0A0A; font- 
  weight:normal">December 2020</span>
 author: <span style="font-size:18px; font-family:'Arial'; color:#0A0A0A; float:left; font- 
 weight:normal">Analysis Bureau</span>
date: <span style="font-size:18px; font-family:'Arial'; color:#0A0A0A;font-style:normal; 
float:left">2/2/2021</span>
output: 
 ioslides_presentation:
 css: styles.css
 logo: something.png
```

I have found ways to add blank spaces after something. This would only exacerbate the issue and push my items further down and eventually they would not show up. Using LaTeX and/or pandoc, HTML, or any other method, is there a way to move the title, author, date items up on the page and not push them down?

I have tried using custom CSS but does not seem to work. I use custom CSS because I do not want items vertically centered on the other parts of the document.

Answer (score 0):

It does not exactly answer the question but the best that i could figure out is to put break tags at the end of the title and subtitle items. Break tags being `<br>` and `</br>`.